# android json starting with string

Tags: android, json

```
returnLogin([{
    "id": 0,
    "first_name": "abc",
    "last_name": "xyz",
    "msg": "Invalid User or Location ID or Password.",
    "location_id": "",
}])
```

How to get data from above Json string? 
here json start with witn string not any bracket thats why i try to. getting data

Comment: Did you even try ? Show your code

Comment: try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            System.out.println("jsonResponse" + jsonObject);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

Answer (score 0):

you can parse like below,

```
String data = "";// here your json data which will parse
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            int id=jsonObject.getInt("id");
            String first_name=jsonObject.getString("first_name");
            String last_name=jsonObject.getString("last_name");
            String msg=jsonObject.getString("msg");
            String location_id=jsonObject.getString("location_id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But before parse correct your data.

Comment: its going in to JSONexception :: org.json.JSONException: Value returnLogin( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Because your data was wrong please correct it,

Comment: please put your original json data,

Comment: its my all the response:: returnLogin([{"id":0,"first_name":"","last_name":"","msg":"Invalid User or Location ID or Password.","location_id":"","reg_id":"","emp_id":"","emp_pass":"","currency_symbol":"","access_timeattendance":"","location_register_services":"","location_manager_req_discount":"","location_manager_req_adjustment":"","access_retail_fast_posting":"","access_retail_fast_posting_new_check":"","check_style":"","print_technician_copy":""}])

Comment: how to removew "returnLogin("  from my json... i thing this remove after solve that insssue

Comment: yes you require to remove it,

Comment: for remove yourresponse.replace("returnLogin("."");

Comment: and also next time yourresponse.replace(")"."");